# Website's responsive menu showing sub menus

Tags: css

I am working on [this](http://www.inspuratesystems.com/mntextile/) website and the site shows sub menu's with the menu's even if they are not opened. I am unable to understand what is causing this issue.

Please guide me. Thanks.

NOTE: The menu shows ALL menu items (menu items and their sub menu items too which it should not show until I hover on the menu item.)
[image]

```
body #navmenu ul.menu li {
/*
    width: 100%;
*/
    width: 60%;

    clear: both;
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 6px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 6px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    /*
    border-top-width: 2px;
    border-right-width: 2px;
    border-bottom-width: 2px;
    border-left-width: 2px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-left-style: solid;
    */
}
body #navmenu ul > li:hover {
    background: #051449 !important;
}
body #navmenu ul.menu li ul li {
    background:#051449!important;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
}
body #navmenu ul.menu li ul li:hover {
    background:#051449!important;
}
body #navmenu ul.menu a, body #topmenu ul.menu ul a {
    background: #051449!important;
    display: inline;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
}
body #navmenu ul.menu a:hover, body #topmenu ul.menu ul a:hover {
    background: #051449!important;
}
/* dropdown */
body #navmenu ul.menu ul {
    width: auto;
    position: static;
    display: block;
    border: none;
    background: inherit;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
body #navmenu ul.menu ul li {
}
```

Comment: Are you talking about the nav menus at the top? Like "Products & Services -> Apparels"?


Because if so, I can't see the second-level menus until I hover over the first-level items. It seems to be working fine. What browser are you using to test it?

Comment: Seems to be a cache issue

Comment: You updated your question. but we still not can reproduce your error

Comment: I added a visual graphic to it.